# The Reject Dialog in the Suggested Edits Review Queue is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just rejected a suggested edit in it's review queue and noticed that the textbox to enter a manual cause for rejection exceeds the size of the surrounding box. It now looks like this:

[image]

Can you maybe adjust the size of the textarea sio that it fits in the dialog or increase the width of the dialog?

Comment: Oded is on a roll today